# Error when creating Angular 2 custom theme: Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes

I am trying to create my own custom themes in Angular 2 but I keep getting an error.

I have tried installing and reinstalling webpack and rebuilding some other modules but nothing has helped.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/themes.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
              ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map
      in C:\Users\Administrator\Dev\MONEY-SAVING\node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss (line 1372, column 16)
```

I am hoping to successfully create my own Angular theme.

Comment: The error is in `./src/app/themes.scss` - so it would help if you showed the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your angular material / animations / cdk to be at least roughly the same version? (check in package.json) That helped for me, see [my bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181182/how-to-fix-error-map-of-map-getmap-key-must-be-a-map-in-angular-stac)

If this is not the issue, a colleague talked about having fixed a similar sass-loader problem recently, there should be Node or Node Package Manager bugs pointing to this.